# Height of the content doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As you can see in the picture below, my content height is broken on higher resolutions
[image]

Then, if I add `height:100vh` on the whole content it works good for bigger resolutions, but in small resolutions I lose the content below and I can't scroll to it.
[image]

What am I missing in the code that causes this problem?

```html
<div style="height: 100vh;">
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <section class="content-wrap full">

    <!-- Preorder -->
    <section class="youplay-banner">

      <div class="image" style="background-image: url(./l2/assets/images/banner-bg.jpg);">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="info container">
        <div>
          <center>
            <div class="container text-center" style="width: 100vw">
              <div class="welcome">
                <img src="./l2/assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- See countdown init in bottom of the page -->
            <div class="countdown h2" data-end="2020/07/01"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <iframe width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/47mH4zuFFjk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br><br>
            <!-- Social Buttons -->
            <div class="social">
              <div class="container" data-bottom-top="opacity: 0;" data-bottom="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="row icons">
                  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.l2arena.ml">
                      <i><img src="./l2/assets/images/fbc4ca.png?1"></i>
                      <span>Share on Facebook</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http%3A//www.l2arena.ml">
                      <i><img src="./l2/assets/images/twc4ca.png?1"></i>
                      <span>Share on Twitter</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A//www.l2arena.ml">
                      <i><img src="./l2/assets/images/g%2bc4ca.png?1"></i>
                      <span>Share on Google+</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Social Buttons -->
            <!--<br><br>
                        <a href="/home" class="btn">Continue to website</a>-->
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
    </section>
    <!-- /Preorder -->
  </section>
  <!-- /Main Content -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I just added @media(min-height: 1000px) and gave height:100vh and it fixed my problem.

Comment: iis there ay missing styles in this demo ? what is `image` class styles ?

Comment: Please stop using `<br>` to add space between elements. Use `margin` or `padding`.

Comment: Also `center` is obsolete and should no longer be used.

Comment: .youplay-banner .image {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0px; }

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i deleted the <br> but its same

Comment: @MahirMersimoski please also include CSS.

Comment: @Vepthy that would be too much code and i wont be able to post the question, if you want i can send you specific class css code here

Comment: As @Paulie_D mentioned, you need to reduce your code to a [mre]. Cut out all of the code that doesn't affect what you're asking about; use dummy images instead of real images; dummy text instead of real text, etc., until you're left with a small amount of code that displays the problem you're having.